# Transformation matrix for the reflecttion about the plane $x+y=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

I tried to make it by applying the transformation to the standard basis vectors giving me the matrix: $\begin{bmatrix}
0 &  -1&0 \\ 
 -1&  0& 0\\ 
 0&  0& 1
\end{bmatrix}\\$
is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well let's think about the eigenspaces of this transformation.  $(1,1,0)$ is a vector orthogonal to this plane, so it's reflection should just be $(-1,-1,0)$ (i.e. span$(1,1,0)$ is one eigenspace).

Then two vectors in the plane are $(1,-1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$ (the span of these is the other eigenspace).  So these vectors should stay the same under this transformation.

These three vectors form a basis for $\Bbb R^3$ so we just need the matrix $A$ such that $A(1,1,0) = (-1,-1,0)$, $A(1,-1,0)=(1,-1,0)$, and $A(0,0,1)=(0,0,1)$?

From here we use linearity to find the matrix $A$.

So first we decompose our basis vectors into their coordinates wrt the standard basis:
$(1,1,0) = (1,0,0)+(0,1,0)$, $(1,-1,0)=(1,0,0)-(0,1,0)$, and $(0,0,1)$ is already a standard basis vector.

Why have I done this?  Because $A(1,0,0)$ is just the first column of $A$ (verify this for yourself).  Like $A(0,1,0)$ and $A(0,0,1)$ are the second and third columns of $A$, respectively.

I'll denote the $i$th column of $A$ as $A_i$.  Then $A(1,1,0) = A_1 + A_2 = (-1,-1,0)$, $A_1-A_2 = (1,-1,0)$, and $A_3=(0,0,1)$.  Look, we've already found the third column of $A$!  Yay!

Now let's looks at our other two equations: $\begin{cases} A_1 + A_2 = (-1,-1,0) \\ A_1 - A_2 = (1,-1,0)\end{cases}$.

This tells us that $2A_1=(0,-2,0) \implies A_1=(0,-1,0)$.  Plugging this into either of the two equations above we get that $A_2 = (-1,0,0)$.

So your matrix is just $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

which is exactly what you found yourself.  Good job!

Comment: by linearity, do you mean making a system of equations?

Comment: I mean for instance $A(1,1,0) = A(1,0,0)+A(0,1,0)$.  And $A(1,0,0)$ is just the first column of $A$ and $A(0,1,0)$ is just the second column of $A$.

Comment: @Sean Do you understand what I did?

Comment: ya for the most part, eigenspaces are fairly new to me so its slightly confusing but I should be fine.

Comment: I was trying to find a basis of vectors such that the transformation of those vectors was easy to see without having to calculate anything.  Eigenvectors are ideal for that -- so each of the three vectors I chose were eigenvectors (as you can check for yourself).

Comment: Could I use a similar strategy if i was given the result of a transformation on 3 different vectors, and needed to find the transformation matrix?

Comment: Any matrix can be found if you know how it maps one basis set.

Comment: ok thanks, guess I can't use that strategy because the vectors given are not eigenvectors. Anyways thank you I'll try and figure this next one out.

Comment: *Any* matrix can be found if you know how it maps *any* basis set.  That basis doesn't need to be a set of eigenvectors -- they're just often particularly easy to figure out.

Comment: So once we get it setup like you have in your second comment, how would we solve for the columns of A

Comment: It'll be a system of equations problem -- but with vector variables.  Can you figure it out from there or should I just finish this problem to show you an example?

Comment: Wouldn't A be another variable? I know its simple, but  I'm not seeing it

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been on in a few days.  I went ahead and finished the problem for you.